# Retrieving ID of subdocument after update in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I wrote a service to push a new data to my collection using update statement and I need to retrieve the id of last inserted data. I am using `db.collection.update` for this, but it just giving a response like this:

```
{
  "result": {
    "ok": 1,
    "nModified": 1,
    "n": 1
  }
}
```

My api for that is:

```
app.post('/feeds',function(req,res) {
    var _id         = req.body._id;
    var title       = req.body.title;
    var description = req.body.description;
    var latitude    = Number(req.body.latitude);
    var longitude   = Number(req.body.longitude);
    db.user.update(
        {_id:_id },
          {$push : {
              feed:{
                title: title,
                description:description,
                latitude:latitude,
                longitude:longitude

              }
          }
        },function (err,result) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({"success": '0', "message": "Error adding data"});
            }
            else {
                res.json({'result':result});
            }
        });
});
```

This is my Mongoose schema:

```
var user = new mongoose.Schema({

  username : {type: String},
  email    : {type: String,index: {unique: true}},
  password : {type: String},
  feed     : [{
                title        : {type: String},
                description  : {type: String},
                latitude     : {type:Number},
                longitude    : {type:Number},
                feedImages   : [{
                                imageUrl: {type: String}
                               }],

             }]
});
```

I want to add data to feed.

My database structure

[image: database]

I want the id of newly pushed feed.

Comment: You are trying to insert a new record or trying to update an existing record?

Comment: There won't be any id for the newly pushed feed available on update.

Comment: No, an Id is generating when i push data. But the problem is in retrieving. I can see the Id in database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Embedded way (current schema)

If you want to use one document per feed and pushing sub-documents into (embedded way), you can pre-assign a `_id` to your newly created feed `sub-document`:

```
var feedId = new ObjectId();

db.user.update({
  _id: _id
}, {
  $push: {
    feed: {
      _id: feedId,
      title: title,
      description: description,
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude

    }
  }
}, function(err, result) {
  /* ...your code... */
});
```

Don't forget to add a index for `user.feed._id` if you want to query for this field (using `ensureIndex` or`createIndex` depending of your [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) version).

### Using separate collection

As alternative way, you can use a separate feed collection, and use `insert` statements including a `userId` foreign key.

You can find more about pro/cons using [Multiple Collections vs Embedded Documents here](http://openmymind.net/Multiple-Collections-Versus-Embedded-Documents/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `db.user.insert()` , why do you need the id, when you already have it from the req body?

```
db.user.insert(objectToInsert, function(err,docsInserted){
    console.log(docsInserted);
});
```

Comment: when i using insert a error is shown:  TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score -1):

It's a good case for [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate).

> Finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg, passing any options, and returns the found document (if any) to the callback. The query executes immediately if callback is passed.
>
> Available options
>
> **new**: bool - if true, return the modified document rather than the original. defaults to false (changed in 4.0)

Comment: As I understand the question, he wants to get the ID of the subdocument and not the one of the document (which he already knows).

Comment: @str: he will get the entire document back, including the subdocuments and their ids.

Comment: ... and would have to filter a potentially large amount of subdocuments that could even have duplicates. Not ideal.

Comment: @str: agree. Pre-assigning ids seems to be the best. This is the next best thing, though. :)