# How can I find pushed subdocument ids in mongoose during update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I am trying to find `_id` of subdocuments that I insert into an array inside my document using `doc.updateOne`. How can I find `_id` of newly pushed subdocuments?

This is what I've tried. But I'm afraid that when too many updates happen, I get a wrong `_id`

```
await model.updateOne({
    _id: docId
}, {
    $push: {
        arr: {a: 3, b: 4}
    }
});

const freshData = await model.findById(docId);
const id = freshData.arr[freshData.arr.length - 1];

console.log(id); // _id will be printed (But what if another $push happen before findById?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246116/retrieving-id-of-subdocument-after-update-in-mongodb)

I only had to create `ObjectId` before updating my document and assigning that `ObjectId` to newly inserted subdocument `_id`.
Here is a simple code that solves the problem:

```js
const _id = new ObjectId();

await model.updateOne(
    { _id: docId },
    {
        $push: {
            arr: {_id, a: 3, b: 4}
        }
    });

console.log(_id); // _id will be printed
```